# Dealing with DST time with set_levels function [multiindex pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I observe a strange observation with function index.set_levels of pandas 0.15.0.
When I change the timezone to Europe/Paris with infer, the 2am hour of october is tripled.

Has someone a solution to this problem ?

```
array = [('s001', d) for d in pd.date_range(start='01/01/2014', end='01/01/2015', freq='H')] + [('s002', d) for d in pd.date_range(start='01/01/2014', end='01/01/2015', freq='H')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(array, names=['sce', 'DATES'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index)
df = df.append(df.query('DATES == "26/10/2014 02:00:00"'))
df = df.query('DATES <> "30/03/2014 02:00:00"')
df = df.sort()
df[7151:7160]
```

the output is:

```
sce  DATES                        
s001 2014-10-26 00:00:00  0.342909
     2014-10-26 01:00:00 -0.575897
     2014-10-26 02:00:00 -1.469307   <<<< ok
     2014-10-26 02:00:00 -1.469307   <<<< ok
     2014-10-26 03:00:00 -1.277365
     2014-10-26 04:00:00  1.252814
```

then:

```
df.index  = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(1).tz_localize('Europe/Paris', ambiguous = 'infer'), level=1)
df[7151:7160]
```

the output is:

```
sce  DATES                              
s001 2014-10-26 01:00:00+02:00  0.342909
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+02:00 -0.575897   <<<< nok   
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00 -1.469307   <<<< ok
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00 -1.469307   <<<< nok
     2014-10-26 03:00:00+01:00 -1.277365
     2014-10-26 04:00:00+01:00  1.252814
```

---

Then if I go through simple index

```
df = df.reset_index('sce')
df = df.tz_localize('Europe/Paris', ambiguous = 'infer')
df = df.set_index('sce', append=True)
df[7151:7160]
```

the output is :

```
DATES                     sce           
2014-10-26 00:00:00+02:00 s001  0.342909   <<<< ok
2014-10-26 01:00:00+02:00 s001 -0.575897   <<<< ok
2014-10-26 02:00:00+02:00 s001 -1.469307   <<<< ok
2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00 s001 -1.469307   <<<< ok
2014-10-26 03:00:00+01:00 s001 -1.277365   <<<< ok
2014-10-26 04:00:00+01:00 s001  1.252814   <<<< ok
```

The second method gives good result but it is very much longer for big multiindex dataframe (16000 for dates and 200 for sce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, see issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8694)

The works is a work-around, I think might be a bug in that the levels themselves are not inferring the ambiguous time zone properly.

```
In [91]: def works(df):
   ....:     return df.reset_index(level=1,drop=True).set_index(df.index.get_level_values(1).tz_localize('Europe/Paris', ambiguous = 'infer'),append=True).iloc[7151:7160]
   ....: 

In [92]: def breaks(df):
   ....:     return df.set_index(df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(1).tz_localize('Europe/Paris', ambiguous = 'infer'),level=1)).iloc[7151:7160]
   ....: 

In [93]: array = [('s001', d) for d in pd.date_range(start='01/01/2014', end='01/01/2015', freq='H')] + [('s002', d) for d in pd.date_range(start='01/01/2014', end='01/01/2015', freq='H')]

In [94]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(array, names=['sce', 'DATES'])

In [95]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index)

In [96]: df = df.append(df.query('DATES == "26/10/2014 02:00:00"'))

In [97]: df = df.query('DATES <> "30/03/2014 02:00:00"')

In [98]: df = df.sort()

In [99]: works(df)
Out[99]: 
                                       0
sce  DATES                              
s001 2014-10-26 00:00:00+02:00 -0.833819
     2014-10-26 01:00:00+02:00 -1.190427
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+02:00 -1.210017
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00 -1.210017
     2014-10-26 03:00:00+01:00  0.763599
     2014-10-26 04:00:00+01:00 -1.055695
     2014-10-26 05:00:00+01:00 -0.912766
     2014-10-26 06:00:00+01:00  0.373625
     2014-10-26 07:00:00+01:00  0.631287

In [100]: breaks(df)
Out[100]: 
                                       0
sce  DATES                              
s001 2014-10-26 01:00:00+02:00 -0.833819
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+02:00 -1.190427
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00 -1.210017
     2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00 -1.210017
     2014-10-26 03:00:00+01:00  0.763599
     2014-10-26 04:00:00+01:00 -1.055695
     2014-10-26 05:00:00+01:00 -0.912766
     2014-10-26 06:00:00+01:00  0.373625
     2014-10-26 07:00:00+01:00  0.631287
```

Comment: I see you have planned a correction for the 0.15.2 :) Thx !

Comment: Yep, we are going to release 0.15.1 soon, so this will be in the next release. Pull requests are welcome!